# NtQueryDirectoryFile enumerate files partial and continue from previous 

Tags: c, winapi, filesystems, msdn

As i need to create an application using Nt level apis only , Here i want to write a wrapper for same behaviour of `Ntquerydirectoryfile` ,so i collect lot of things abt this api ,but i could not understand some in this api .

```
NTSTATUS status = ZwQueryDirectoryFile(FileHandle,Event,ApcRoutine,ApcContext,IoStatusBlock,FileInformation,Length,FileInformationClass,ReturnSingleEntry,FileName,RestartScan);
```

Here `IoStatusBlock(out)` contains Information and status of queried dir or file ,status should be a return type of this api and information should be data written into `fileinformation` and `fileinformation` having full details(any `fileinformation` class structure) of given file/dir then length - how much data should fill ..

o/p parameters are `IOstatusblock` and `fileinformation` only

[ZwQueryDirectoryFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff567047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

here i saw an one property of this api which was enumerating a drive with some allocated length it fetches some files from it ,then return details partial regarding to length After that, Zwquerydirectory call comes again with same handle with some other length ,**it fetches the data from last received one of previous call** ..its only i could not understand ,because where should the api set this information to remind the position to start exact location(offset)...if u know abt it let me know ,it really appreciative...